# downloading mp4 files in Google Chrome

Tags: nginx, webserver

specify how to configure the server to the fact that he gave the mp4 file to load it in the G Chrome?
When you click on the link downloads a file is opened in a browser that is not very acceptable.
I was looking for ... They said that you must configure the header, but I do not quite understand where it needs to be done.
It is also advised to change:
application/file mp4;
or remove this extension is quite mimetypes

**I also tried:**

```
location /files { 

     if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?/([^/]*?)$) 
     { 
             set $filename $1; 
             add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$filename"; 
     }
```

}

, but nothing changed.

What to do?
I'll be glad to any advice. Thank you.

---

I also know that mp4 files can be issued to the user for download, as implemented in savefrom.net

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a little bit wrong header `Content-Disposition`

```
add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=\"$1\"";
```

Also you don't need `set filename $1;` (with my example) it should be removed.
For me such method works fine.

Comment: Code should look like, do you? grace

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute "download" like

```
<a href='file.mp4' download='Very-Very-Good.mp4'>download</a>
```